# OnMapRedady info window

Tags: android, google-maps

building a location based app

i add markers to the map and info window when the marker is clicked

code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    UiSettings uiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    uiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    mMapCoastLocationService.init(mMap);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // set the markers - new
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.map_marker_info_contents, null, false);
            //ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.marker_info_window_icon);
            //icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.info);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.marker_info_window_title);
            title.setText(marker.getTitle());
            return view;
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Integer coastId = mMapCoastLocationService.getCoastIdByMarker(marker);
            startCoastDetailsActivity(coastId);
        }
    });


    mFocusMyLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            focusMyLocation();
        }
    });
}
```

xml for marker:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/marker_info_window_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="info image"
        android:src="@drawable/info" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marker_info_window_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"`enter code here`
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marker_text_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marker_text_margin"
        android:text="example"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is that the first time i run the app, when i click a marker i get only the text and not the icon and the click isnt working

the second time everything working great.

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Google Maps InfoWindow renders the InfoWindow into a bitmap before displaying it (when clicked)
That means that if you have an image source from the web or a big local resource to load into an ImageView inside the InfoWindow it might not be completed before the InfoWindow rendering has finished..

The second time you are loading the image the InfoWindow is already rendered so it will appear..

The solution (using Glide is as follow):

```
public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = MarkerInfoWindowAdapter.class.getName();;

    private static Context mContext;
    private static View mapInfoWindow;
    private static ImageView infoWindowIcon;
    private static TextView infoWindowTitle;
    private static TextView infoWindowDetails;
    private static TextView infoWindowCount;

    public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mapInfoWindow = ((SessionsActivity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_info_layout, null);
        infoWindowIcon = (ImageView) mapInfoWindow.findViewById(R.id.session_icon);
        infoWindowTitle = (TextView) mapInfoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
        infoWindowDetails = (TextView) mapInfoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
        infoWindowCount = (TextView) mapInfoWindow.findViewById(R.id.attenders_count);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return manageMarkerInfo(marker);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Refresh");
        refreshInfoWindow(marker);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        MapHelper.clickInfoItem(getContext(), marker);
    }

    private View manageMarkerInfo(Marker marker){
        if (marker.getTitle() == null || marker.getTitle().length() == 0 || marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Log.i(TAG, "NO Info");
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
            return null;
        } else{
            Log.i(TAG, "Regular Info");
            return selectMarker(marker);
        }
    }

    private View selectMarker(final Marker marker) {
        if (MapHelper.newSessionMarker != null || marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(mContext.getString(R.string.session_create))) {
            infoWindowTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
            infoWindowDetails.setText(LocationHelper.getCountryAddressFromCoords(
                    marker.getPosition().latitude,
                    marker.getPosition().longitude));

            infoWindowCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("user_image_url"))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.add_session)
                    .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(mContext))
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Error loading Image");
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target,
                                                       boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Success loading Image");
                            getInfoContents(marker);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .error(R.drawable.add_session)
                    .into(infoWindowIcon);
            return mapInfoWindow;
        } else{
            SessionObject session = MapHelper.selectedSessionByUser;
            infoWindowTitle.setText(session.getSessionMarker().getTitle());
            infoWindowDetails.setText(LocationHelper.getCountryAddressFromCoords(
                    session.getSessionMarker().getPosition().latitude,
                    session.getSessionMarker().getPosition().longitude));

            infoWindowCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (session.getAttendersCount() > 0) {
                infoWindowCount.setText("" + session.getAttendersCount());
                infoWindowCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                infoWindowCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (session != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Select Session:");
                Log.d(TAG, "Session Title: " + session.getSessionObject().getString("title"));
                Log.d(TAG, "Session Image: " + session.getSessionObject().getString("session_image_url"));
                Log.d(TAG, "Session GeoPoints: " + marker.getPosition().latitude + ", "
                        + marker.getPosition().longitude);
                Log.d(TAG, "Session Attenders:" + session.getAttendersCount());
                if(session.getSessionObject().getString("address") != null &&
                        session.getSessionObject().getString("address").length() > 0){
                    infoWindowDetails.setText(session.getSessionObject().getString("address"));
                }

                int defaultIcon = Constants.sessionTypesList.get(session.getSessionObject().getInt("type")).getResources()[0];
                try {
                    Glide.with(mContext)
                            .load(session.getSessionObject().getString("session_image_url"))
                            .placeholder(defaultIcon)
                            .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(mContext))
                            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target,
                                                           boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Error loading Image");
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target,
                                                               boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Success loading Image");
                                    getInfoContents(marker);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                            .error(defaultIcon)
                            .into(infoWindowIcon);
                    return mapInfoWindow;
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    return mapInfoWindow;
                }
            }else{
                return mapInfoWindow;
            }
        }
    }

    private void refreshInfoWindow(Marker marker){
        if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Success loading Image");
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }

    private Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public SessionObject getSessionFromMarker(Marker marker) {
        for (SessionObject session : ((SessionsActivity)getContext()).sessionsList) {
            if (marker.getId().equals(session.getSessionMarker().getId())) {
                return session;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately the image I load into the marker info I a small locally stored XML. I also tryed without it. I jet the text I need (the marker name) bit not the functionality

Comment: You may only have one OnClickListener inside each InfoWindow and it's the InfoWindow iteslf..That's why the click is not being called

Comment: i have only one